# Symfony - Return type for Doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Since php7 we already know that it is possible to declare the function's return type. Then if that function returns something else, an exception is thrown.

Now I would like to use this new feature when a function in my Symfony project returns a Doctrine entity. So I tried to declare a function like this:

```
public function getEntity(array $conditions, string $entityClass): ?object
{
    // some logic...
    return $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(1)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

As you can see it must return `null` or `object` variable. However, it seems that `object` doesn't work as expected because I got an exception:

> Type error: Return value of
>   HelperBundle\MyHelper::getEntity()
>   must be an instance of HelperBundle\object or
>   null, instance of AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity returned

I'm actually not sure about what this message means: should returned object derive from a class located in `HelperBundle` or what?

But generally speaking, is there a way to declare a return type for a generic Doctrine entity without using custom base classes or interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just now read an article about this and it's not supported to have a return type-hinting as object

You can however in PHP 7.2:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php

Comment: You are slightly mistaken in "or null" part. Nullable types are introduced in php 7.1, see http://php.net/manual/ru/migration71.new-features.php.

Answer (score 1):

To address you first question, I will just say that this declaration

```
public function getEntity(array $conditions, string $entityClass): ?object
```

is understood by PHP <7.2 as if you declared `object` class in `HelperBundle` namespace.

Comment: I was relying on PhpStorm since it gives no error so I thought it was already available from php 7.1... my fault :\